# multiplication formula vba that is copied on worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

this vba is meant to enter in column J on worksheet YYYY the result of the multiplication between col I and col G but when I click my vba button column J is still blank (to copy down the formula from row 2 in column J). Any thoughts on how to solve this would be appreciated.

```
With Sheets("YYYY")
  With .Range("J2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp))
    .Formula = "=I2*G2"
    .Value = .Value
  End With
End With
```

Comment: Why the `.Offset(, 0)`?  It does not do anything.  Just do `.Formula = "=I2*G2"` and `.Value = .Value`

Comment: You say that it's meant to enter on sheet YYYY (4 Ys), but in the code it shows `Sheets("YYYYY")` (5 Ys).  Could that be the issue? Do you have another sheet named YYYYY in addition to YYYY so the formula is getting populated in the wrong sheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that your cells in column `J` are initially blank, so the range you are updating is not the range that does have data in columns `I` and `G`.
For this reason you were updating only the first one or two cells. That's because `.Cells(.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp)` yields the last populated cell on column `J`, which is `J1` if column `J` is not populated.

To catch the rows that are populated in column `I` for instance, you can try instead:

```
With .Range("J2:J" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row)
```

Or similarly, catch the populated rows in column `I` then move right to `J`:

```
With .Range("I2", .Cells(.Rows.count, "I").End(xlUp)).Offset(0,1)
```